# Zedc dataset compression using JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

What is zEDC dataset compression? How can we apply compression on our mainframe datasets. What are the DATACLAS parameter values used for zEDC compression.

Please help

Thanks,
Sunitha S

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A [search with Google](https://www.google.com/#q=zEDC) turns up a number of IBM sites that look promising, along with some SHARE presentations which are usually quite excellent.  In any case, the proper first step is to discuss with your z/OS Systems Programmer and Storage Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

DATACLAS names are installation-dependent. As @cshneid said you'll probably have to talk to your local storage administrator / system programmer. Or, if you have access to ISMF, you can look for dataclasses that have the compaction parameter set to ZEDC Required (ZR) or ZEDC Preferred (ZP).

Note that there are multiple system configuration things that need to be done to enable the actual utilization of zEDC. So again, talking to the local experts is really the best/recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with randomScott. You can get in touch with you system administrator to get info on dataclas and msgclass.

One quick way i used to follow is, put 'Z' in front of dataset and enter. Your pds will be compressed. This works only when none of the user are accessing that particular pds.

Comment: Just to clarify, the type of compression you get when you "put Z in front of dataset" has nothing to do with zEDC. The type of compression you describe is what you needed to do to re-organize a PDS dataset to reclaim the unused space...think of it like defragmenting your hard disk on your PC. zEDC is a compressed filesystem - as you write data, the system is automatically compressing the records so that the files take less space. Two very different things.